# Write to two columns

Tags: bash, shell, logging, multiple-columns

I am trying to log some data, the first one is number of cpu core and memory. How can I write the CPU to the first column and memory to the second?

```
#!/bin/bash

    while true;
            do nproc >> system.log & free -m | grep Mem: | awk '{print $2}' >> system.log
            sleep 5
    done
```

system.log:

```
1246
1
1246
1
1246
1
1246
1
1246
1
1246
1
1246
1
1246
```

I want it to look like this:

```
1246   1
1246   1
1246   1
1246   1
1246   1
1246   1
1246   1
1246   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be the easiest

```
$ pr -2ats' ' file

1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246
```

or, similarly

```
$ paste -d' ' - - <file

1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246
```

and mandatory `awk` solution

```
$ awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS' file

1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246 1
1246
```

to combine with your script

```
... grep Mem: | awk '{ORS=NR%2?FS:RS; print $2}'
```

Comment: Can I do it in the bash script before while writing to the file ?

Comment: yes, add the `ORS=...` inside your awk print statement.

Comment: Could you show me? I tried to do it,  but cant make it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true;
do
    echo "`nproc`  `free -m | grep Mem: | awk '{print $2}'`" >> system.log
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: That throws some errors: `./data.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token done
./data.sh: line 6: `done'`

Comment: @user3580316 That's odd... I don't have that syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU bash:

```
printf "%s %s\n" $(< file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
#!/bin/bash --
while true; do
        printf "%s %s\n" $(nproc) "$(free -m | grep Mem: | awk '{print $2}')" >> system.log
        sleep 5
done
```

The test:

```
$ chmod +x log_monitor.sh
$ ./log_monitor.sh
^C

$ cat system.log
8 16082
8 16082
8 16082
8 16082
8 16082
```